# Div apperas on second hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on custom tooltip that ollows cursor, but it's only firing on second hover. I searched stack from floor to ceiling and all those advices i tried wasn't very helpful. I made code as simple as possible, but stil all works on second hover. I'm out of ideas.

Here is the code

```
$(".bar").bind('mouseover',handler);
$(".bar").bind('mousemove', function(e){
  $('.tail').css({
      left:  e.pageX + 20,
      top:   e.pageY
  });
});


function handler(ev) {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var elId = target.attr('id');
    if( target.is(".bar") ) {       
        $('#'+elId).hover(function() { 
           $('#tail'+elId).show();
        }, function() { 
           $('#tail'+elId).hide(); 
        });
    }
}
```

And here goes the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3070/

Thanks or help.

**EDIT**
Whoa guys, that was really fast! All your solutions worked. +1 for everyone. But solution from MrUpsidown is most elegant... Thanks to all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe do something easier:

```
$(".bar").bind('mouseenter', function () {

    $('#tail' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
});

$(".bar").bind('mouseleave', function () {

    $('#tail' + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
});

$(".bar").bind('mousemove', function (e) {

    $('#tail' + $(this).attr('id')).css({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3274/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attaching the `hover` event when `mouseover`. You should attach the `hover` event at the beginning, like this:

```
$(".bar").each(function(index,elem){
    var target = $(elem);
    var elId = target.attr('id');
    if( target.is(".bar") ) {
       $('#'+elId).hover(function() {
           $('#tail'+elId).show();
        }, function() { 
           $('#tail'+elId).hide(); 
        });

        $('#'+elId).bind('mousemove', function(e){
            $('#tail'+elId).css({
               left:  e.pageX + 20,
               top:   e.pageY
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you init the hover function only when JS bind the mouseover.

You have to directly use hover method.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that the first hover yo do only binds the element to the function. I slightly modified your script, automatically running .show() and conditioning .hide() to a mouseout event. Like this:

```
function handler(ev) {
var target = $(ev.target);
var elId = target.attr('id');
if( target.is(".bar") ) {
   $('#tail'+elId).show(); 
   $('#'+elId).mouseout(function() { 
        $('#tail'+elId).hide();            
    });

    $('#'+elId).bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $('#tail'+elId).css({
           left:  e.pageX + 20,
           top:   e.pageY
        });
    });
}
```

}

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/cc7s9rcf/
I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `display:block` in this javascript

```
    $('#'+elId).bind('mousemove', function(e){
       $('#tail'+elId).css({
           left:  e.pageX + 20,
           top:   e.pageY,
           display:'block'
       });
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3273/

Answer (score 0):

Try this update

```
$(".bar").bind('mouseover',handler);
/*
$('.bar').hover(function() { 
        $('.tail').show();
    }, function() { 
        $('.tail').hide(); 
});
*/
function handler(ev) {
    console.dir(ev);
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var elId = target.attr('id');

    if( target.is(".bar") ) {
        console.dir(ev.type);
        if (ev.type === 'mouseover') {
            $('#tail'+elId).show();
        } else {
            $('#tail'+elId).hide(); 
        }
        /*
       $('#'+elId).hover(function() { 
           $('#tail'+elId).show();
        }, function() { 
           $('#tail'+elId).hide(); 
        });*/

        $('#'+elId).bind('mousemove', function(e){
            $('#tail'+elId).css({
               left:  e.pageX + 20,
               top:   e.pageY
            });
        });
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3276/